# Is there an easy way to move shared directories between volumes?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, windows-xp, network-share

We have a single-domain forest, and a handful of different file servers.  One file server in particular has me worried: it is hosting a lot of important data on independent disks and no backup has ever been done.  It's also running Windows XP Pro.

I've already taken steps to bring in a backup system (not just for this server, but a larger solution).  My problem is really to do with setting up this system for redundancy - I need that data to stay online, or at least be very quickly recoverable (waiting for backups to restore is going to be too slow).

The current system setup (after a few maintenance windows) has 3, 1TB SATA drives.  C is the system volume.  Volume F contains all of the shared directories, and volume E is completely empty.  No money is going to be spent on this box, so what I want to do is move all the shared directories to the OS volume as a temporary backup while I delete both the E and F partitions, mirror the disks in Disk Management, format the mirrored volume, and copy the shares back onto the now-mirrored volume.

My question is this: are there any tools to help me copy the shares to other volumes and automatically re-create the share at the new physical location with the share/ntfs security permissions intact or am I stuck doing this manually?

*Update*

So it turns out that XP doesn't support mirrored disks anyway.  Bleh.  Not used to dealing with XP performing server roles...

Decided it would be best to schedule a backup to retain copies of the data on the open disk until management can figure out a budget for a real file server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have three potential answers for you.  You are welcome to choose your favorite:

1. <s>If software RAID on Windows XP is anything like software RAID on Server 2003, you should be able to delete drive F, convert drive E to a dynamic disk, and then add the former F drive as a mirror, all *without* moving any data around manually.</s>
2. If the above is not possible in XP, here is the direct answer to your question: [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) with the /COPYALL switch will enable you to copy file structures around without altering attributes, including NTFS permissions.  File shares are stored in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Shares, so you could backup and restore this registry key if re-creating them is not a more convenient option.
3. If you happen to have a file server running Server 2008 R2 with RAID storage and sufficient available disk space, another approach would be to:

   1. [Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx) the XP box, saving the VHD file(s) to the new server.
   2. Use Disk Management to mount the VHD file(s) and then re-create the share names on the new server.
   3. Make the change entirely transparent to the end-users by adding a CNAME record referring the old server name to the new one and setting HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters\DisableStrictNameChecking to 1.

Comment: #1 works on 2003, but not XP because it doesn't support mirrored drives.  I should have realized that before asking this question.  However, marked as answered for all the useful information: including the registry location for the systems shares.

Comment: Good to know. I've given answer #1 the strikethrough treatment for benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

To backup the shares you can use regedit and notepad. See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125996